# Background video height and fixing header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using the Typo HTML template to make a website. This template: http://nunforest.com/typo-demo/video/

I want the video to be of 80% of the landing pages' height, so that the nav bar would appear and be about 15% from the bottom of the page. Basically I want the video container to be smaller, not with a 100% height like in the template but 80%. The video should not resize its width but it should constrain the proportion and hide the overflow at the top.

The problem is that even when I edit the file the video resizes itself. Another problem is that the nav bar "catches" and fixes itself to the top of the page when you scroll over it, but because I want to change the height of the landing page, it still catches the top of the page on the spot where it was before the change of height.

Could anyone point out the parts to edit?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Find and replace the following HTML in your source code.

```
<video class="" preload="" width="100%" height="80%" poster="http://themepunch.com/revolution/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/video_space_cover.jpg" style="display: block;"> 
                                    <source src="http://themepunch.com/revolution/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/among_the_stars.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                    <source src="http://themepunch.com/revolution/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/among_the_stars.webm" type="video/webm">
                                </video>
```